# unable to signin with google in ionic using angular-6-social-login

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-social-login

Unable to sign in with google in ionic app by using angular-6-social-login.it is working fine on browser but in the case of app after give the credentials it shows white blank page.my code is below

```
public socialSignIn(socialPlatform: string) {
let socialPlatformProvider;
if (socialPlatform == "facebooks") {
  socialPlatformProvider = FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID;
} else if (socialPlatform == "google") {
  socialPlatformProvider = GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID;
}

  this.socialAuthService.signIn(socialPlatformProvider).then(
    (userData) => {
      this.socialUserEmail = userData.email;
      this.socialId = userData.id;
      this.socialName = userData.name;
      this.insertsociallogindetails();
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
      alert(error);
    }
  );
```

}

and here is screen
[image]

Please give me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
I used this package 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-firebase-auth
maybe it helps

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**
Unfortunately Capacitor is not available for firebase-ui neither ngx-firebaseui. You will have to do the login by yourselve with the angularFireAuth method. signInWithProvider if memory doesn't fail